# Why is Bitbucket README not showing up on project overview, despite source showing file exists?

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my project overview page I see that it shows:
[image: README isn't here yet]

Despite going to my source page and seeing that there is in fact a README.md:
[image: README is here]

Comment: try to create it with "Create a README" button if you will have 2 files maybe you have the typo in your README.md name

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

Answer (score -3):

Why not try Bitbucket Wiki?

All you need to do is to enable it in Settings of your repository, please follow these steps:

The repository administrator can choose whether repository includes a Wiki or not. To enable a Wiki for a repository, do the following:

- **Click Wiki in the settings navigation.** (from you repository)
  You can choose from Public Wiki or Private Wiki. 
  A private Wiki is only visible to people who have permission to see it. Anyone can view, edit, or create pages for a public Wiki.
- **Select the type of Wiki**
- **Click Save.**

You will see a new button - "Wiki" in the left navigation panel. 
When you click on it, you will see the default Wiki welcome Home page.

You can also clone it to your local environment (your laptop/pc) with:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/YOUR_ACCOUNT/YOUR_REPO.git/wiki
```

this link will be displayed on our welcome page.

Hope this helps!